# Как написать функцию является ли пользователь участником сообщества Вконтакте для сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию на сайт через **ВК**, чтобы при попадании на сайт пользователю показывалось окно входа и кнопка *"войти через вконтакте"*, но зайти могли только те, кто состоит в моей закрытой группе.
Как написать функцию для проверки, является ли пользователь участником сообщества Вконтакте?

Просмотрел **VK API**  `groups.isMember` подходит для этого..не могу сообразить, как правильно это сделать.. Может кто помочь советом или логикой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С **API VK** толком не работал, но, если посмотреть их документацию, то можно заметить, что при авторизации вызывается callback функция, в которой собственно можно и проверить является ли пользователь членом вашей группы.
https://vk.com/dev/openapi_auth

Пример:

```
VK.Auth.login(function(response) { 
  if (response.session) { 
    /* Пользователь успешно авторизовался */ 
    if (response.settings) { 
      /* Выбранные настройки доступа пользователя, если они были запрошены */ 
    } 
    // проверяем является ли пользователь членом группы
    if (VK.Groups.IsMember(group_id, user_id)) {
      // член группы
    } else {
      // не член
    }
  } else { 
    /* Пользователь нажал кнопку Отмена в окне авторизации */ 
  } 
});
```

---

А ещё как вариант, можно повесить обработчик события на `auth.login`.
https://vk.com/dev/openapi_observer

Пример:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?84"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.init({
    apiId: XXXXXX
  });
</script>
<div id="vk_like"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {
    type: "button"
  });
  VK.Observer.subscribe("auth.login", function f() {
    // проверяем является ли пользователь членом группы
    if (VK.Groups.IsMember(group_id, user_id)) {
      // член группы
    } else {
      // не член
    }
  });
</script>
```